# Auto scroll as input is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day everyone!

I would like to know how can I enable auto scroll? 
Currently when you type in to many commands on my website you have to manually scroll down with the mouse to see the response. You also can't use the arrow keys since they are currently being used to iterate through the commandhistory. I was doing research by scrolling down with jquery automatically but none of them worked at all!

The idea behind the website is that it should function like a terminal and as you enter an input and receive output the window should scroll down automatically like a normal terminal does.

At the moment I've tried grabbing focus to the div class however this was not successful. I've also tried using this

I've also tried using this piece of code:

```
$('terminal').animate({
    scrollTop: $('terminal').get(0).scrollHeight
}, 1500);
```

However I think it didn't work since there is no scrollbar at the beginning and it only scrolls once in the beginning and not continuously as stuff is prompt.

Here is my [website](https://bitvivaz.github.io/) and the code for it can be found at the github repo [here](https://github.com/bitVivAZ/bitVivAZ.github.io)

Thank you for your time!

my index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <title>BitVivAZ Terminal</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&subset=Latin">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="window">
                <div class="handle">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button class="close">
                        </button>
                        <button class="minimize">
                        </button>
                        <button class="maximize">
                        </button>
                    </div>
                        <span class="title"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="terminal"></div>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

my index.js file:

```
var username = prompt("Please enter your name:", "name");
if (username === null ){
    username = "user";
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    // COMMANDS
    function ls(){
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            terminal.append(files[i].name + "\t\t");
        }

        terminal.append(lineBreak);
    }

    function nano(args) {
        var str = args;
        var fileFound = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (str.toString() === files[i].name){
                fileFound = true;
                terminal.append(files[i].content + lineBreak);
            }
        } 
        if (!fileFound) {
            terminal.append("cannot access \'" + str + "\' : No such file or directory" + lineBreak);
        }
    }

    function clear() {
        terminal.text("");
    }

    function echo(args) {
        var str = args.join(" ");
        terminal.append(str + "\n");
}

    function date(){
        // Get the date for our fake last-login
        var date = new Date().toString(); date = date.substr(0, date.indexOf("GMT") - 1);
        terminal.append("Today is " + date + lineBreak);
    }

    function help(args){
        var str = args;
        if (str.toString() === "") {
            terminal.append("Supported commands are:" + lineBreak); 
            terminal.append("\t -  ls:  list directory contents" + lineBreak);
            terminal.append("\t -  nano:  open and print files. e.g. nano [FILENAME]" + lineBreak);
            terminal.append("\t -  clear:  clear the terminal screen" + lineBreak);
            terminal.append("Bonus Commands are:" + lineBreak);
            terminal.append("\t -  echo:  prints input as text in the terminal. e.g. echo [INPUT]" + lineBreak);
            terminal.append("\t -  date:  return today's date and current time." + lineBreak);

        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++){
                if (str.toString() === commands[i].name){
                    terminal.append(commands[i].help + lineBreak);
                }
            }
        }

    }


    // END COMMANDS

    var title = $(".title");
    var terminal = $(".terminal");
    var prompt = username + "@vivaz";
    var path = ": ~";
    var lineBreak = "<br>";

    var commandHistory = [];
    var historyIndex = 0;

    var command = "";
    var commands = [{
                    "name": "clear",
                    "function": clear
            }, {
                    "name": "help",
                    "function": help
            }, {
                    "name": "echo",
                    "function": echo
            }, {
                    "name": "date",
                    "function": date
            }, {
                    "name": "ls",
                    "function": ls
            }, {
                    "name": "nano",
                    "function": nano
            }];

    var files = [{
                    "name": "README.md",
                    "content": lineBreak + "Name: Martin" + lineBreak + "Surname: Buxmann" + lineBreak + "Date of Birth: 23/02/1996" + lineBreak + "Place of Birth: Pretoria, South Africa" + lineBreak + lineBreak + "Created to learn and to create anything from gfx to programming" + lineBreak
            }, {
                    "name": "github.txt",
                    "content": "<a href=\"https://github.com/bitVivAZ\">GitHub Website</a>"
            }, {
                    "name": "projects.txt",
                    "content": 
                                lineBreak + 
                                "<div class=\"project_title\">Severe Gaming Website</div>" + 
                                lineBreak + 
                                "I have huge passion for eSports especially for DOTA 2 and thought it would be a great way " + 
                                "to learn Django and Python by creating a website for Severe Gaming, a multi gaming organization that I manage!" + lineBreak + 
                                lineBreak + 
                                "Made using: Django, Python, CSS, HTML, jQuery" + 
                                lineBreak + 
                                "Github repo : <a href=\"https://github.com/bitVivAZ/SeveregamingZA\" target=\"_blank\">https://github.com/bitVivAZ/SeveregamingZA</a>" + 
                                lineBreak + 
                                "Domain : <a href=\"https://www.severegaming.co.za\" target=\"_blank\">https://www.severegaming.co.za</a>"  + 
                                lineBreak
            }];


function processCommand() {
    var isValid = false;

    // Create args list by splitting the command
    // by space characters and then shift off the
    // actual command.

    var args = command.split(" ");
    var cmd = args[0];
    //console.log(cmd);
    args.shift();

    // Iterate through the available commands to find a match.
    // Then call that command and pass in any arguments.
    for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
            if (cmd === commands[i].name) {
                    commands[i].function(args);
                    isValid = true;
                    break;
            }
    }

    // No match was found...
    if (!isValid) {
            terminal.append(command + ": command not found" + lineBreak);
    }

    // Add to command history and clean up.
    commandHistory.push(command);
    historyIndex = commandHistory.length;
    command = "";
}

function displayPrompt() {
    terminal.append("<span class=\"prompt\">" + prompt + "</span>");
    terminal.append("<span class=\"path\">" + path + "</span> ");}

// Delete n number of characters from the end of our output
function erase(n) {
    command = command.slice(0, -n);
    terminal.html(terminal.html().slice(0, -n));
}

function clearCommand() {
    if (command.length > 0) {
            erase(command.length);
    }
}

function appendCommand(str) {
    terminal.append(str);
    command += str;
}

/*
//  Keypress doesn't catch special keys,
//  so we catch the backspace here and
//  prevent it from navigating to the previous
//  page. We also handle arrow keys for command history.
*/

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var keyCode = typeof e.which === "number" ? e.which : e.keyCode;

    // BACKSPACE
    if (keyCode === 8 && e.target.tagName !== "INPUT" && e.target.tagName !== "TEXTAREA") {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (command !== "") {
                    erase(1);
            }
    }

    // UP or DOWN
    if (keyCode === 38 || keyCode === 40) {
            // Move up or down the history
            if (keyCode === 38) {
                    // UP
                    historyIndex--;
                    if (historyIndex < 0) {
                            historyIndex++;
                    }
            } else if (keyCode === 40) {
                    // DOWN
                    historyIndex++;
                    if (historyIndex > commandHistory.length - 1) {
                            historyIndex--;
                    }
            }

            // Get command
            var cmd = commandHistory[historyIndex];
            if (cmd !== undefined) {
                    clearCommand();
                    appendCommand(cmd);
            }
    }
});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    // Make sure we get the right event
    e = e || window.event;
    var keyCode = typeof e.which === "number" ? e.which : e.keyCode;

    // Which key was pressed?
    switch (keyCode) {
            // ENTER
            case 13:
                    {
                            terminal.append("\n");

                            processCommand();
                            displayPrompt();
                            break;
                    }
            default:
                    {
                            appendCommand(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
                    }
    }
});

$(terminal).trigger("focus");


// Set the window title
title.text(username + "@VivAZ:~");

// Display Welcome Message
terminal.append("Welcome " + username + ", to the bitVivAZ Terminal!" + lineBreak);
terminal.append("Some supported commands are:" + lineBreak);
terminal.append("\t -  ls:  list directory contents" + lineBreak);
terminal.append("\t -  nano:  open and print files. e.g. nano [FILENAME]" + lineBreak);
terminal.append("\t -  clear:  clear the terminal screen" + lineBreak);
terminal.append("\t -  help: lists all supported commands." + lineBreak);
displayPrompt();


});

$('terminal').animate({
    scrollTop: $('terminal').get(0).scrollHeight
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define scrolling function which will measure div height and scroll to bottom, ie:

```
function scrollToBottom() {
    $('.terminal').scrollTop($('.terminal')[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

and execute it inside displayPrompt().

Answer (score 0):

When you press Enter, you should scroll the .terminal to the bottom :

```
 let terminal = document.querySelector(".terminal");
 terminal.scrollTo(0,terminal.scrollHeight); //scrolls the height of the terminal
```